# Recursive data structures going wrong - incompatible types when assigning List from type struct *l

Tags: c, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I've made a binary tree where there are essentially three levels of structs:

```
typedef struct l {
  char n[15];
  struct l *next;
} List;

typedef struct {
  char rname[20];
  char lname[20];
  List number;
} info;

typedef struct tree {
  info thisnode;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
} Tree;
```

and on this line of code

```
 t->thisnode.number = t->thisnode.number.next;
```

I get the error mentioned in the title

Normally with recursive data structures these type of assignments work, despite next having type struct *l. Could anyone help me work out why in this case it isn't working?

Also I would instinctively have the above line as

```
 t->thisnode.number = t->thisnode.number->next;
```

But my compiler seems to like that even less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the types surely are incompatible.

The type of the `next` field in `number` is `struct l *`, but the type of `number` in `info` is `List`, which is an alias for `struct l`, i.e. the entire struct, not just a pointer to it. So you're trying to assign a pointer into an entire structure, which won't fly.

It seems you're missing a pointer level, perhaps the `number` field in `info` should be `List *`?

Comment: Hmmm I did like you suggested and changed the number in info to List * and this lets me make the assignment, and has gotten rid of a lot of the compiler errors I was getting (once I changed all the number.n to number->n).

But in my main function I am getting a seg fault after inserting one entry, whilst with the same code before I added the List struct I wasn't having this problem. I'm gonna fiddle with it a bit but I get the feeling that C doesn't like that 3 level struct, or is it fine?

Comment: Well it seems I forgot to malloc when 'number' when assigning to number->n[x] and this seems to have fixed the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `t->thisnode.number` is of type `List` (i.e. `struct l`) while `t->thisnode.number->next` is of type `struct l *` (well, would be if it actually compiled as you access a non-pointer member with the pointer access syntax).